# name.toLowerCase is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, filtro

estoy intentando filtrar resultados a través de un input con JS. O sea, cuando escribo letras en el input se supone que solo debería ver los países que tienen las letras que escribí. Pero no hace eso y en la consola veo un error.

Este es el código del input que tengo en html:

```
<header class="container filter-content my-2">
    <form class="form-search" id="formulario">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a country" id="inputFormulario">
    </form>
```

Tengo un form.js:

```
const formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');
const inputFormulario = document.getElementById('inputFormulario');

const clientForm = data => {
     formulario.addEventListener('keyup', e => { 
        e.preventDefault()
        const letraCliente = inputFormulario.value.toLowerCase() 
        //console.log(letraCliente)       
        const arrayFiltrado = data.filter(item => {
            const letraApi = item.name.toLowerCase()  
            if (letraApi.indexOf(letraCliente) !== -1) {  
                return item
            }
        })
        banderillas(arrayFiltrado)
        console.log(arrayFiltrado)   
    })
}
```

Y este es app.js:

```
const banderas = document.getElementById('banderas')

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e => {
    fetchData()
})

const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('api.json') //en lugar de api.json ahi puedo pegar la url de la api
        const data = await res.json()
        //console.log(data)
        banderillas(data)
        clientForm(data) //es para poder usar la func creada en form.js y que tome la data
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}

const banderillas = data => {
    let elementos = ''
    data.forEach(item => { 
        elementos += `
        <article class="card"> 
            <img src="${item.flags.svg}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            <div class="card-content">
                <h3>${item.name.common}</h3>  
                <p>
                    <b>Population: </b>
                    ${item.population}
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>Capital: </b>
                    ${item.capital}
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>Region: </b>
                    ${item.region}
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>Subregion: </b>
                    ${item.subregion}
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>Currency: </b>
                    ${item.currencies}
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>Languages: </b>
                    ${item.languages}
                </p>
                <b>
                    <a target="_blank" href="${item.maps.googleMaps}">Map</a>
                </b>
                
            </div>
        </article>
        `
    });
    banderas.innerHTML = elementos
}
```

El error que me aparece en la consola es:

```
Uncaught TypeError: item.name.toLowerCase is not a function
    at form.js:10:40
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (form.js:9:36)
(anónimo) @ form.js:10
(anónimo) @ form.js:9
```

Vi que algunos usuario en preguntas similares sugieren hacer toString antes del toLowerCase, probé y no solucionó nada. Y aunque estaba siguiendo un video y creo que está todo igual, no encontré ningún error y no sé cómo lo puedo solucionar. ¿Qué recomiendan que haga? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir qué valor de respuesta te da cuando haces un console.log de `console.log(typeof item.name)`?

Comment: Hola @DanielRodríguezMeza dice que es un object.

Comment: Bueno eso lo explica todo, a un object no le puedes hacer `toLowerCase`, además no tiene sentido. Más bien deberías hacer eso con alguna propiedad del object que sea algún valor primitivo como `number` o `string`, que para cualquier caso tendrias que converitro a `.toString().toLowerCase()`

Comment: Claro, lo que no sé es por qué me lo toma como objeto, de hecho ya probé con el toString y tampoco pude. De todas formas, encontré una solución diferente así que está listo el problema. Gracias